# creating a variable, calling an image path from a DB and passing it into an image source in php

Tags: php, database, oop

I am trying to display objects for a reminders list with the following fields:
Title
Date Added
and a reminder image (a clock in my case)

Currently i display the object with the following code

```
    class ReminderList{

private $data;

/* The constructor */
public function __construct($par){
    if(is_array($par))
        $this->data = $par;
}


public function __toString(){

    $image = $this->data['image'];

    // The string we return is outputted by the echo statement
    return '
        <li id="todo-'.$this->data['id'].'" class="todo">

            <div>echo'<img src="'$image'">';</div>
            <div class="title">'.$this->data['title'].'</div>
            <div class="date">'.$this->data['date_time'].'</div>

            <div class="actions">
                <a href="#" class="editReminder">Edit</a>
                <a href="#" class="deleteReminder">Delete</a>
            </div>

        </li>';
}
   }
```

The fileds in the DB are
 
title
image (containing a path to the image, not a blob)
and date_time

When creating the object i have it writing the title, creating the time, and then input a path (images/reminder.png).

I get a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING but thats from the way Im declaring the $image variable.

Any thoughts on the correct way to call an image path from a DB and plug it into an img src in php?

My apologies if this is unclear, ive been working with this problem a while

Comment: Why do you have an echo in your return? Does that need to be there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is definitely causing the parse error:

```
 <div>echo'<img src="'$image'">';</div>
```

Change it to this:

```
<div><img src="'.$image.'"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Parse error is gone now, and image is there. I am in utter awe of you sir!